# How to know if client is killed in Awesome WM

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I'm writing a module and it has local table with a list of filtered clients. When one of clients in table is killed all operations with it raise "client is invalid" exception.

So how can I check if client is killed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best would be to add a signal for the `unmanage` event on every client, you add to your list.
In the signal function you can then delete the client from the list of tables. It could look something like this:

```
client.add_signal('unmanage', function(c)
    -- Remove c from your list
end)
```